# I need to identify basic gestures which are performed in surface application?

Tags: wpf, xna-4.0, pixelsense

I need to identify basic gestures which are performed in surface application? My final requirement is to find out basic gestures with their parameters,properties which determine gesture functionality and then pass them to another application.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not included, you'll have to write them yourself by using your Mathskills, `PreviewTouchUp`/`PreviewTouchDown`/`PreviewTouchMove` & `ManipulationDelta`